# "Temporarily Unavailable" message when a menu alias contains "contact"

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu-item, menu, alias

One of the websites we manage, http://wesleyunited.ca , recently started having a problem with menu aliases containing "contact" as a substring: clicking the menu just brings up an empty page that just says "Temporarily Unavailable." This happened spontaneously, we didn't do any work on the website or update anything manually before this problem arose. After we found out about the issue we updated to Joomla 3.9.5 (this was a few weeks ago) but that didn't fix the problem.

As a temporary fix I changed the "Contact Us" menu item's alias so that is doesn't contain "contact", and I made a "Contact (Broken)" sub-menu item which exhibits the error for demonstration purposes.

I played around with different aliases, and found that as long as "contact" is a substring it will not work, but everything I tried without it was fine. Even "contac" and "ontact" work. It also doesn't have to be separated out with hyphens, something like "blcontactah" will cause the error. I tried adding "contact" to the aliases of the other menu items (not just the "Contact Us" page) and it broke those as well. Even if a menu item has "contact" in the alias and a sub-menu item does not, the sub-menu's link will still give the error, I guess because "contact" is still in the url.

Does anyone have any idea for why this is happening? Did our server spontaneously decide to start blocking urls containing the string "contact", and if so how do I disable that?

Comment: When you see this message, is it coming from Joomla, or is it a server error page? Getting any error status code? Can you share a link to the page with the issue?

Comment: It just says "Temporarily unavailable" on a white screen. The website is http://wesleyunited.ca/ , please check out the "Contact Us" item in the top menu

Comment: I changed the menu structure so that the "Contact Us" link works now (it's a live site so it needs to have something working) and added a "Contact (Broken)" sub-menu item to show the error message.

Comment: Well, there is a 503 error generated - which is a server error. I am not sure if this is produced by Joomla or if it's something else on the server level - but I tried a few "fake" urls on the site like http://wesleyunited.ca/contact-me/contact - that normally shouldn't exist and Joomla would return a 404 error and I got the 503 error again. So it looks to me that this something outside of Joomla -without being 100% certain-, but 1. I would enable error reporting and debug to see if I can get any more meaningful error note and I would clone the site and tried on another environment.

Comment: Also check the error logs on your server, check your .htaccess (if you have) for anything that could be creating the issue (rename/disable it for a while to test), ask your hosting provider for help as well (since this is a server error).

Comment: @William I would also like to see the .htaccess script (assuming it has been modified by somebody).  Often developers with only a loose handle on regex patterns are writing the conditions in that file.

Comment: @mickmackusa I checked the site's public_html folder and there is only an htaccess.txt rather than .htaccess (which, to my knowledge, means that the file is being ignored). In any case, the htaccess.txt file doesn't have any custom redirects, and doesn't contain any references to "contact" at all, it looks like a default Joomla file. If you want I could still post a full copy of it.

Comment: @FFrewin If I turn on Debug mode and navigate to the broken link, it just brings up the blank page and doesn't load the Joomla debug information. When I check their website's error logs, I see a LOT of failed login attempts, so something(s) out there is probably attempting something malicious with the website, but I'm not sure that would be causing this problem. I will try cloning it to another environment and see if that works.

Comment: @FFrewin I cloned the website to my local server and it's still exhibiting the same behaviour.

Comment: Something that's odd is that I can't actually find the 503 Error being reported in any logs. I've tried setting the log file explicitly in the website's php.ini file but it's not working, possibly because I don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: Start disabling plugins and extensions one by one, test the frontend and see what happens. Do you have any SEF extension installed? Any special hacks or customizations?

Comment: It can also be something "broken" in your database, leftovers or an update that didn't went well. Maybe in the assets table or something with the alias. This is very specific issue and it actually needs professional hands-on debugging and troubleshooting. - Deconstruct and reconstruct piece by piece the site until you find what' the cause.

Comment: @FFrewin I did find an SEF plugin, but disabling it didn't solve the problem. I will have to talk to my bosses about doing more thorough troubleshooting, since the website was done for a charity and they can't afford to pay us for a lot of work (and so my bosses can't afford to pay *me*).